# Start fresh instance of app, prevent tombstoning

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, silverlight-4.0

I developed an app that is working fine on windows phone. The nature of the app is such that it need not support tombstoning. That is, a fresh instance can be started each time.

The question is how do i prevent tombstoning my app? For example, if a user clicks on start button while in the app, i need to terminate the app, so that when he hits back key, the app starts with a fresh instance.

Any help would be greatly appreciated! :)

Comment: With Mango tombstoning isn't instant, as it used to be, to enable Fast App Switching for the user. Why do you want to prevent this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In each page you have's OnNavigatedTo (Or you could override PhoneApplicationPage) just set a variable that has each page check return to the original page. From there, you can just restart as if it was the beginning.

Apologies if function names are not 100%, typing this without Visual Studio Available.

Some logic..
In App.xaml.cs

```
public static bool Activated = false;

ApplicationActivated()
{
  Activated = true;
}
```

in each page:

```
 public override void OnNavigatedTo(object sender, NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
       base.OnNavigatedTo(sender,e);
        if (App.Activated)
              if (NavigationService.CanGoBack){
                     NavigationService.GoBack();
                     return; //remember that GoBack() is async and will not cause this function to end early! you must return

              }
              else { App.Activated = false; } 

        }

    }
```

Comment: krolth and @willmel thanks for the detailed response. I still couldnt find a solution to my problem though. Ill elaborate a little more. I have a app with a single page that uses the camera and a dispatch timer object. It works perfectly when I launch it from the start menu. When I use the start key or back key to terminate the app, I get errors when I restart. I suspect that this is because the OS is trying to save the state of the timer and camera object, but is not able to do successfully. I just need to make sure that the app starts afresh each time, no matter how it is launched. :)

Comment: I found a way to fix this! I just added a buffer page infront of the main app page. I use this to create a new instance of the main page when the app is resumed after deactivation. Not very elegant. But it works! :) Thanks all...

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do this from the Application_Activated event. In preMango you would typically do something like this:

```
    private void Application_Activated(object sender, ActivatedEventArgs e) 
    { 
        var state = PhoneApplicationService.Current.State; 
        if (state.ContainsKey("YourKeyName")) 
        { 
            // Typically rehydrate. Clear app state
        } 
    }
```

In Mango you might need to use the IsApplicationInstancePreserved property as well. This property indicates when the data was preserved for you and you don't event need to load it. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.phone.shell.activatedeventargs.isapplicationinstancepreserved(v=vs.92).aspx.

So you would need to add something like this:

```
if (e.IsApplicationInstancePreserved) 
   {
       // Clear State
   }
```

Comment: @Frazell Tombstoning or being placed in dormant stage wreaks havoc on my app and I can't figure out how to fix it. :(